# How would you setup this DIV layout (Right aligned div on left, Left aligned Div on right)?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to have 2 seperate DIV's, one with Right aligned content (the labels) and the other div with Left aligned content (the content for each label).

I am hoping to make each label "connected" with it's child content on the right so that if it gets pushed down by content from above they will still remain together.

What would be the best way to approach setting this type of layout that is cross-browser? (I have provided in a JPG below).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alignment is going to be tricky if you actually have the right aligned content in that separate div, especially if the content is variable in nature and the height is prone to change.

Very basically, here is what I would do just so that the right hand features always line up with their associated left hand content. You're obviously going to have to tweak it to your taste.

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-left: 150px;
}

ul li h3{
    position: absolute;
}

ul li span {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
    left: -150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3><span>Feature 1</span></h3>
        <p>Content 1<br />Content 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><span>Feature 2</span></h3>
        <p>Content 2<br />Content 2</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I literally just threw this into an empty file just to make sure it works. I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

As I'm being accused of providing an overkill solution, here's a simpler one just using floats:

CSS:

```
.left, .right {
    float: left;
}

.left {
    clear: left;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left">feature</div>
<div class="right">content<br />content</div>

<div class="left">feature</div>
<div class="right">content<br />content</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh, this seems to do the trick just fine.  I did not NEED to have 2 seperate DIVs, that was just my amateur idea.  :)

Comment: Is it a problem that this solution shows errors on W3C validator?

The document type does not allow element "h3" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag <span><h3>Feature 1</h3></span>

The mentioned element is not allowed to appear in the context in which you've placed it. This might mean that you need a containing element, or that you've forgotten to close a previous element.

One possible cause for this message is that you've attempted to put a block-level element inside an inline element (such as "<a>", "<span>", or "<font>").

Comment: @Joe Really? Try flipping it around so instead of `<span><h3>` do `<h3><span>`. Let me know if it works and I'll update the code (you need to flip over the CSS too).

Comment: Quite overkill, all you need is floats: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/

Comment: @reisio I guess it's down to personal preference. I'm not very fond of floats and avoid them when I can. I've updated with some code, since your link (while generally helpful on its topic) didn't provide a specific solution.

Comment: Hey Leigh, my mistake I overlooked that.  No problems now!

Answer (score 1):

This is semantically a table, and is an appropriate use for the HTML table layout.  While it's important to move away from the use of tables for non-tabular layout, a table is still a table, no matter how few rows or columns.  A table with two columns and lots of rows is very prevalent in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can also have classes within the divs aligned left or right within the parent element.